# Php file sometimes causing 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php

So, in our company we have branches. Each branch has been given a set of tasks they must complete on a daily/weekly/monthly basis.

I've written a script that summarizes which tasks have been completed for every single branch for the current month. Now, this can take a long time depending on how much data there is. (Usually increases as the month goes on)

At the start of the month, everything works fine. Towards the middle/end of the month is when the problems start happening (usually because there's more data to check, due to there being more days).

This is the code that calls the function to summarize everything (which is also the page that throws the 500 error):

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 3600);
require_once('../../Connections/newConn.php');
require_once('../../Library/new/branchTaskSummary.php');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$summary = array();
if(isset($_GET['month']) && isset($_GET['year']) && isset($_GET['update'])) {
    global $conn;
    $update = $_GET['update'] == 1;
    $month = $_GET['month'];
    $year = $_GET['year'];
    if(!$update) {
        $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT data_json, DATE_FORMAT(last_updated, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i') AS last_updated FROM branchtasksummarydata WHERE month = ? AND year = ?");
        $query->bind_param('ii', $month, $year);
        $query->execute();
        $result = $query->get_result();
        if($result->num_rows > 0) {
            $summary = $result->fetch_assoc();
        } else {
            $summary = summariseEverything($month, $year);
        }
    } else {
        $summary = summariseEverything($month, $year);
    }
}
echo json_encode($summary);
?>
```

It calls a function called `summarizeEverything` which is where all the magic happens.

Here is the code for that function:

```
function summariseEverything($month, $year) {
    global $conn;
    $now = new DateTime();
    $data = array();
    $daysInMonth = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);
    $start = sprintf("%s-%s-%s", $year, $month, "01");
    $end = sprintf("%s-%s-%s", $year, $month, $daysInMonth);
    //Get all branches
    $branches = getBranches();
    //Get all tasks
    $dailyTasks = getAllTasks(1, $start, $end);
    $weeklyTasks = getAllTasks(2, $start, $end);
    $monthlyTasks = getAllTasks(3, $start, $end);
    //Get dates
    $dailyDates = Calendar::getDaysBetween($start, $end);
    $weeklyDates = Calendar::getWeeksBetween($start, $end);
    $monthlyDates = Calendar::getMonthsBetween($start, $end);
    foreach($branches as $branch) {
        $instance = array("id" => $branch["id"], "name" => $branch["name"], "area" => $branch["area"], "finance_area" => $branch["finance_area"], "company" => $branch["company"], "icb" => $branch["icb"], "tasks" => array());
        $instance["tasks"]["completed"] = 0;
        $instance["tasks"]["daily"]["completed"] = 0;
        $instance["tasks"]["weekly"]["completed"] = 0;
        $instance["tasks"]["monthly"]["completed"] = 0;
        //Do daily tasks.
        foreach($dailyTasks as $task) {
            foreach($dailyDates as $date) {
                $dateObj = new DateTime($date);
                if($dateObj > $now) {
                    break;
                }
                $isWorkingDay = true;
                Calendar::isBankHoliday($dateObj->format('Y-m-d'), &$Colour, &$Msg, &$isWorkingDay);
                Calendar::isWeekend($dateObj->format('Y-m-d'), &$Colour, &$Msg, &$isWorkingDay);
                $dayName = $dateObj->format("l");
                $isOpen = branchIsOpen($branch, $dayName);
                if($isWorkingDay && $isOpen) {
                    $instance["tasks"]["total"] += 1;
                    $instance["tasks"]["daily"]["total"] += 1;
                    $instance["tasks"]["daily"][$task["department"]]["total"] += 1;
                    $instance["tasks"]["daily"][$task["department"]][$task["id"]]["total"] += 1;
                    $completed = taskCompleted($branch["id"], $task["id"], $date." 00:00:00", $date." 23:59:59");
                    if($completed) {
                        $instance["tasks"]["completed"] += 1;
                        $instance["tasks"]["daily"]["completed"] += 1;
                        $instance["tasks"]["daily"][$task["department"]]["completed"] += 1;
                        $instance["tasks"]["daily"][$task["department"]][$task["id"]]["completed"] += 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(!$instance["tasks"]["daily"][$task["department"]][$task["id"]]["completed"]) {
                $instance["tasks"]["daily"][$task["department"]][$task["id"]]["completed"] = 0;
            }
            if(!$instance["tasks"]["daily"][$task["department"]]["completed"]) {
                $instance["tasks"]["daily"][$task["department"]]["completed"] = 0;
            }
        }

        //Do weekly tasks.
        foreach($weeklyTasks as $task) {
            foreach($weeklyDates as $date) {
                $instance["tasks"]["total"] += 1;
                $instance["tasks"]["weekly"]["total"] += 1;
                $instance["tasks"]["weekly"][$task["department"]]["total"] += 1;
                $instance["tasks"]["weekly"][$task["department"]][$task["id"]]["total"] += 1;
                $completed = taskCompleted($branch["id"], $task["id"], $date["start"], $date["end"]);
                if($completed) {
                    $instance["tasks"]["completed"] += 1;
                    $instance["tasks"]["weekly"]["completed"] += 1;
                    $instance["tasks"]["weekly"][$task["department"]]["completed"] += 1;
                    $instance["tasks"]["weekly"][$task["department"]][$task["id"]]["completed"] += 1;
                }
            }
            if(!$instance["tasks"]["weekly"][$task["department"]][$task["id"]]["completed"]) {
                $instance["tasks"]["weekly"][$task["department"]][$task["id"]]["completed"] = 0;
            }
            if(!$instance["tasks"]["weekly"][$task["department"]]["completed"]) {
                $instance["tasks"]["weekly"][$task["department"]]["completed"] = 0;
            }
        }

        //Do monthly tasks.
        foreach($monthlyTasks as $task) {
            foreach($monthlyDates as $date) {
                $instance["tasks"]["total"] += 1;
                $instance["tasks"]["monthly"]["total"] += 1;
                $instance["tasks"]["monthly"][$task["department"]]["total"] += 1;
                $instance["tasks"]["monthly"][$task["department"]][$task["id"]]["total"] += 1;
                $completed = taskCompleted($branch["id"], $task["id"], $date["start"], $date["end"]);
                if($completed) {
                    $instance["tasks"]["completed"] += 1;
                    $instance["tasks"]["monthly"]["completed"] += 1;
                    $instance["tasks"]["monthly"][$task["department"]]["completed"] += 1;
                    $instance["tasks"]["monthly"][$task["department"]][$task["id"]]["completed"] += 1;
                }
            }
            if(!$instance["tasks"]["monthly"][$task["department"]][$task["id"]]["completed"]) {
                $instance["tasks"]["monthly"][$task["department"]][$task["id"]]["completed"] = 0;
            }
            if(!$instance["tasks"]["monthly"][$task["department"]]["completed"]) {
                $instance["tasks"]["monthly"][$task["department"]]["completed"] = 0;
            }
        }
        $data["branches"][] = $instance;
    }
    $json = json_encode($data);
    //Check if data exists for this month & year before inserting into DB.
    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT summaryPK FROM branchtasksummarydata WHERE month = ? AND year = ?");
    $query->bind_param('ii', $month, $year);
    $query->execute();
    $result = $query->get_result();
    $exists = $result->num_rows > 0;
    if($exists) {
        //Data already exists, so let's update it.
        $query = $conn->prepare("UPDATE branchtasksummarydata SET data_json = ?, last_updated = ? WHERE month = ? AND year = ?");
        $query->bind_param('ssii', $json, $now->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"), $month, $year);
        $query->execute();
    } else {
        //No data exists, so we will insert it.
        $query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO branchtasksummarydata (year, month, last_updated, data_json) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $query->bind_param('iiss', $year, $month, $now->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"), $json);
        $query->execute();
    }
    return array("data_json" => $json, "last_updated" => $now->format("d/m/Y H:i"));
}
```

Now when I call this function, it will hang for around 6/7 minutes before giving me an internal server error.

The funny thing is, I test it on my local machine and it works fine. However, on the live server, it throws the error.

**EDIT**

After coming back to try and fix this issue, I turned on any error logging I could and it just gives me these with each iteration of looping through branches:

```
Notice: Undefined index: total in C:\WS\JMIS\Library\new\branchTaskSummary.php on line 61

Notice: Undefined index: total in C:\WS\JMIS\Library\new\branchTaskSummary.php on line 62

Notice: Undefined offset: 9 in C:\WS\JMIS\Library\new\branchTaskSummary.php on line 63

Notice: Undefined index: total in C:\WS\JMIS\Library\new\branchTaskSummary.php on line 63

Notice: Undefined offset: 12 in C:\WS\JMIS\Library\new\branchTaskSummary.php on line 64

Notice: Undefined index: total in C:\WS\JMIS\Library\new\branchTaskSummary.php on line 64
```

Without the logging, it throws a 500 internal server error. I cannot for the life of me figure out what's going on! The code works, I've tested it on multiple local systems. Yet doesn't seem to work on the live server which I do not have access to.

Comment: What do the logs say? Or else add some logging yourself and see where it goes awry. There is so much code and business logic going on, that it'd be really hard to help you just based in your post alone.

Comment: A 500 error will nearly always mean an error message logged somewhere. You need to find out *what* error was thrown. My money would be on out of memory, or execution time exceeded, due to the increased data. Both limits can be raised, but you may also be able to tweak your function so it processes the data more efficiently.

Comment: The only php error logs are just warnings, nothing related to my code.

Comment: As for the total warnings - you don't define it in `$instance = array(...`, so adding it in here should get rid of those warnings.

Comment: Could be that you're running out of memory and not time. Try doubling the memory limit and see if it lasts any longer before giving the 500. `ini_set('memory_limit','256M');` replace 256 with double whatever the current memory limit is.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I solved the issue. It was an `IIS FastCGI` activity timeout configuration.

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

to find your error.

Answer (score 4):

Time for some good old debugging. A 500 error is a server error so it could be anything. Comment everything off, them turn it on per line/block. If the error triggers and it's a function, go into that function an repeat.

At some point you will find the line(s) that trigger this error. From that point you try to figure out *why* that line triggers the warning.

You might be lucky and find it in a log (or sometimes it's the log that's full, it happens). You might want to check the apache and mysql logs, as it could also be a database issue.

Answer (score 0):

500 Internal server error is a server error and it is caused by the fact that apache cannot execute part of your scripts due to some reasons.

Best way to check what the error is, is to open your error log file in apache folder and trace the line.

This shouldnt be hard for you to solve i guess

Comment: We don't use apache, we use IIS and run Php.

Comment: My guess is that you are not logging the php error as expected. Kindly look into this URL https://serverfault.com/questions/19561/how-can-i-display-and-log-php-errors-on-iis7. . don't forget to mark it as answer if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Error 500 is very hard to handle and cause for many reasons like:

1) .htaccess misconfiguration

2) Apache misconfiguration

3) PHP depcrated functions

4) Memory leak

5) Weak server

6) and etc

First, test above solutions if you do not succeed then use error logging apps like [Bugsnag](https://www.bugsnag.com/) or [sentry](https://sentry.io/welcome/)

Answer (score 0):

**For all the undefined notice you can set the value to 0 , if not set.**
For example :-

```
$instance["tasks"]["total"] += 1;
```

In this case you will come across undefined notice if the value for                         **$instance["tasks"]["total"]** is not set yet, at this particular instance.

**So the solution to this could be :-**

```
if (!isset($instance["tasks"]["total"])) {
   $instance["tasks"]["total"] = 0;
}
$instance["tasks"]["total"] += 1;
```

Having this logic in-place everywhere you have such value assignments, should solve your undefined issues .

For Undefined offset problem you can again check if the value isset before :- 
For Example :-

```
if(!$instance["tasks"]["monthly"][$task["department"]][$task["id"]]["completed"]) {
        $instance["tasks"]["monthly"][$task["department"]][$task["id"]]["completed"] = 0;
    }
```

Here you will come across undefined offset notice if your value for 
**$instance["tasks"]["monthly"][$task["department"]][$task["id"]]["completed"]**

Is not set , so the solution to this could be :-

```
    if (isset($instance["tasks"]["daily"][$task["department"]][$task["id"]]["completed"]) && !$instance["tasks"]["daily"][$task["department"]][$task["id"]]["completed"]) {
          $instance["tasks"]["daily"][$task["department"]][$task["id"]]["completed"] = 0;
    }
```